# REGEX Match for all values in a column VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to match a pattern in all rows of column A. If cell value of column A matches the pattern, then a formula to look for last non-blank value in column B needs to be populated in respective cell of column B. The patterns i am trying to match are :- P 1st *, P 2nd *, P 3rd *, P 4th *, P 5th *,...,P 10th *, E 1st *, E 2nd *,....., E 10th *, P GRND, P * Suite, E * Suite, P * Floor, E * Floor. All these patterns also ends with numbers essentially. The below code is giving error as follows :-

```
Run time error '5017' Application-defined or object-defined error
```

for line `set matches = rgx.Execute(c.value)`

```
Dim n2 As Long
Dim nrng As Range, m As Range
Dim rgx As Object, matches As Object
Dim nlr as Long

nlr = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

Set nrng = Range("A2:A" & nlr)

With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "(P|E)\s\(1st|2nd|3rd|4th|5th|6th|7th|8th|9th|10th|GRND)?\(Suite|Floor)?\[d]*"
        For Each c In nrng
            Set matches = rgx.Execute(c.Value)
            If matches.Count > 0 Then
                For Each m In Range("B2:B" & nlr)
                   n2 = m.Row - 1
                   If rgx.test(c.Value) And Range("B" & n).Value = "" Then
                   Range("B" & n2).Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:B" & n2 & "<>""""),$B$2:B" & n2 & ")"
                Next    
            End If
        Next     
 End With
```

Kindly help me achieving the desired output, as i am not too well-versed with VBA.

**EDIT**
Few example of values in Column A which need to be matched against regex.

```
E 1st 2,400- 3500

P 1st 100

E GRND 1,200- 2850

E 2nd 30,000- 58697
```

Comment: Side note: you have a missing `End If` in the deepest `If`. Use `Option Explicit` as there are missing declarations. I would expect an error from this part `Range("B" & N).Value` and N will be zero and there is no row 0 in a sheet.

Comment: Still it is giving the same error for same line,

Comment: What is the value of `c` when it errors?

Comment: That is because your regex is wrong. You have escaped two `(` that you shouldn't plus your pattern is wrong (look at the end part for example where you are planning on number matching). It would help to have some full input strings and expected results indicated. You need also to add in a regex.test(....) line and test for empty strings.

Comment: I have added the input strings examples, I am sorry i am not well-versed with this. What should be the correct Regex or this

Comment: Warcupine - value of c is the very first value of Column A, ie, it is exiting at the very start of the loop

Comment: I meant what is the actual string. Also why are you taking the last row of I and then using only A and B?

Comment: Regex to match your examples: "(P|E)\s(1st|2nd|3rd|[4-9]th|10th|GRND)\s([0-9,]+)(\s[0-9,}+)?" None of your examples show how you expect the words Suite or Floor to appear in your data and your description doesn't make sense with your regex.